# Can't center iframe HTML

Tags: html, iframe

I'm creating a simple web page using only HTML (so I don't use CSS or anything else) and I want to create an iframe in the horizontal center of the page. This is the code

```
<body>
    <iframe height="200" width="800" src="http://www...." align="center" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <!other stuff>
</body>
```

If the alignment is setted as "right", the iframe appears on the right, but if it's setted as "center" (as it is in the code) it appears on the left, as it happens when the alignment is "left".

Thanks to everyone who can help.

Comment: "so I don't use CSS or anything else" — You're trying to do layout. Use CSS. It's designed for it. HTML is not.

Comment: @Quentin I know, but I can't... I'm learning HTML at school and they didn't explain CSS yet. At the moment the teacher wants us to use only HTML.

Comment: Then don't worry about layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the iframe in a div with `align="center"` like this:

```
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <iframe height="200" width="800" src="http://www...." frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Check on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0pwdc27/2) that it is on the center.

**UPDATE**

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) has mentioned in his comment bellow, the use of `align="center"` is obsolete in HTML5. As an alternative you can use `style="text-align:center"` like this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <iframe height="200" width="200" src="http://www...." frameborder="1"></iframe>
</div>
```

Check this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0pwdc27/3/).

Comment: The `<center>` feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea about that. I edited my answer now!

Comment: The [align attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete) has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. The specification says *The following attributes are obsolete (though the elements are still part of the language), and must not be used by authors*

Comment: You don't need a div, just do `iframe { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360010/iframe-position-in-center)).

Answer (score 2):

here is an working code using flex

```
<body style="display:flex;position:relative;margin:0; justify-content: center;">
    <iframe height="200" width="200" src="https://www.w3schools.com" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

</body>
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vp55t0gz/1/)