# iframe position in center

Tags: html, css

So I found this code for position content in the center, but my problem is that it's made for a container, do you know how to make this for iframe? Or do You know another code for that 
Code:

```css
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center"></div>
```

And this is code I need to place in.

```
<iframe src="http://80.213.62.138:12/playbutton.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: see this link for all type of elements centring css : [click here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: just horizontal

Comment: but found out alleredy out how to fix it

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use your code then apply `display:block` to the iframe because most of the browsers read `iframe` as an `inline` element.

```css
iframe {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://80.213.62.138:12/playbutton.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the align to the iframe tag

```
 <iframe align="center" src="http://80.213.62.138:12/playbutton.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: remember the align="center" property of iframe is [**Obsolete since HTML5**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: I'm old fashion guy :( haven;'t fully adopt to html 5 yet